# What's the best way to apply an XSL transform to an XElement?

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

I have a document loaded via XElement.Parse() and I need to apply a XSL transform to it. How would I go about doing this? The only way I know to do is with XPathDocument and I know no way to convert between the two other than XElement->String->StringReader->Stream->XPathDocument.

There must be a better way.

In a related question, what's the best way to apply XPath to an XElement?

Comment: The answer to the additional question is `ex.CreateNavigator()` - great job whoever was in charge of the designing that class.

Comment: @_George Mauer: What about the three methods from Extensions I have mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Oh even better, I hadn't seen that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why not use**:

```
xslt.Transform(xelement.CreateReader(), arglist, someTextWriter);
```

**where** `xelement` **is an [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx)**, `xslt` **is an [`XslCompiledTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163414.aspx)**, `arglist` **is an [`XsltArgumentList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.aspx) and** `someTextWriter` **is a [`TextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx)** ?

**In other words, use this instance method**: **[`XElement.CreateReader()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299560.aspx)**

Or, you can use:

```
xslt.Transform(xelement.CreateNavigator(null), someXmlWriter);
```

**Read more about the** `CreateNavigator()` **extension method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495071.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299124.aspx)**.

The last MSDN link contains a complete code example of an XSLT transformation.

**Update**: This additional question was asked:

> In a related question, what's the best way to apply XPath to an
>   `XElement`?

There are different ways to evaluate an XPath expression over an `XNode`

**[`Extensions.XPathEvaluate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341675.aspx)**

or

**[`Extensions.XPathSelectElements()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx)**

or

[**`Extensions.XPathSelectElement()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156083.aspx)